# Margin when using auto-scaling of parenthesis: Is there a better way than adjusting for it with "\!"?

Tags: brackets, automation

Whenever I need larger parenthesis I use `\left( \right)` which automatically adjusts the size as needed. I know that the optimum would be to always manually choose from `\big, \bigg, \Big, ...` but for my assignments I don't have the time to do that. Now currently, in order to adjust for the margin emerging due to the usage of `\left \right` I always put a `\!` in front of the statement, e.g. `f\!\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)`. Is there a better way than that?

Comment: use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathools` which fixes up the spacing correctly in more cases than just adding `\!` on the left  (or the `mleftright` package which uses a different syntax for essentially the same idea)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the quick answer!